# open mp4 files from orgmode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a .org file with an index of videos I create almost every day as a journal. The idea is that there's a date range for each week, and then under that, a date for each day a video was recorded in.

Now, I'd like to be able to have a link that opens the file in VLC. But when I try to link to the file (C-c C-l), it doesn't seem to agree with me: I can't tab and auto-complete the file's name. The link does start with file:...

the other thing is, if I go ahead and just type in the name of the MP4 file and click on the link, it will simply open the file into Emacs in text, which is not very helpful.

I can't find out how to change that so VLC fires up. This seems to be something very basic, I must be missing something -- but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Help?

(sorry for typos, I'm basically passing out in my chair here, for real).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest I find is using `openwith`.
Get it from melpa then add the following to your .emacs:

```
(require 'openwith)
(openwith-mode t)
(setq openwith-associations '(("\\.mp4\\'" "vlc" (file))))
```

also look at [SO link: How to use an external program as the default way to open PDFs from Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-to-use-an-external-program-as-the-default-way-to-open-pdfs-from-emacs)
Where there are some system specific solutions, some that do not require the `openwith` package.

Comment: Thanks, @manandearth (sorry pressed enter too soon).

I did see this post previously, but I passed right through it because I was looking for an Emacs-native solution. Now, after I've been searching for a while, I guess I am realizing that this is the only (good) way? 

I read about openwith in the Emacs wiki, and over there, it is recommended to switch to [RunAssoc](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RunAssoc) which is very similar. 

out of curiosity, what _is_ the "official" Emacs solution to this?

Comment: there's a code written by Xah Lee [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_dired_open_file_in_ext_apps.html) . but as long as `openwith` works for you...